# Trouble with Morley's theorem proof.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am reading through [this](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/Morley/Bollobas.shtml) proof of Morley's theorem, and I am confused about one part. Why does $\angle ARR_{2}=\beta+\frac{\pi}{3}$? Also, why does the diagram put $\beta+\frac{\pi}{3}$ on $\angle ARQ$ when they say it should be on $\angle ARR_{2}$?

Here is the figure for reference:

[image]

Where $^{+}$ is shorthand for $+\frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: $\alpha + \beta + \gamma + 2\pi/3 = (A+B+C)/3 + 2 \pi/3 = \pi/3+2\pi/3 = \pi$. Thus, any one of $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, along with "$+$" versions of the remaining two, are the angles of a triangle. In $\triangle ARR_2$, there's an $\alpha$, and a $\gamma^+$, so the remaining angle is $\beta^+$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay, first of all we see from $\Delta BRP$ that $\beta + \alpha^+ + \gamma^+ = \pi$. So if you compare this to $\Delta ARQ$, you'll get the $\beta^+$ in question.

To answer the first question,  note that $\Delta ARQ$ and $\Delta ARR_2$ share two equa angle measures.

Comment: Im confused, why does $\beta+\alpha^{+}+\gamma^{+}=\pi$? The sum of the angles of a triangle is $\pi$?

Comment: Ohhhh, they are all radians. I was thinking in degrees. Now let me try this proof again...